# Ask for robust global motion estimation algorithm image processing

Tags: image, image-processing

I am working on a video stabilization project and need a robust algorithm to estimate transformation matrix between adjacent frames.

My present approach is detecting Harris corners on a image and applying optical flow to find correspondent points of those corners on the other. Subsequently, I use RANSAC estimation to find Rigid transform between 2 point patterns, which represents the global motion between the two frames. The thing is, when images are low quality, there are few or even no key points detected, which leads to failed estimation of motion matrix.

Other methods such as block-based (using phase correlation) do not give better performance, from my experience. The most accurate method is image registration based on global motion optimization algorithm, but it's unfeasible for my application in term of computational load.

Could anyone please give me an idea?
Thank in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you targeting?

Comment: Any language, Nyerguds, since I am rather looking for an algorithm. But I prefer C/C++ and Matlab code